# CTC LOSS ERROR InvalidArgumentError: Not enough time for target transition sequence

Tags: keras, ocr

CTC LOSS ERROR InvalidArgumentError: Not enough time for target transition sequence

Answer (score 9, accepted):

your ground-truth (GT) text is too long.
Your input matrix for the CTC loss function has a time-axis with length T. Your GT text must not be longer than T.
Example: input matrix has length 4, your GT text is "world" with length 5, then there is no way that the matrix can contain this text, because it can encode at most 4 chars.

If the GT text contains duplicate chars (like in pi**zz**a), then the CTC algorithm must insert a special character (blank) in between, and your allowed GT length even decreases by 1. 
Some more information about CTC loss: https://medium.com/@harald_scheidl/intuitively-understanding-connectionist-temporal-classification-3797e43a86c

You should check the CTC input length and the length of the GT text (and account for duplicate chars!) for each sample, then it should be easy to identify the one causing this error.